# Shortest way to open file with encoding and readLine() in Java?

Tags: java, file, encoding, readline

What is the shortest way to open file for reading with readLine() method and with setting of it's encoding?

Is the following line correct and shortest?

```
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(
             new FileInputStream(myPath), myEncoding));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29), you can do: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(myPath), myEncoding)` and then `scan.nextLine()` which returns a `String`.